# How to Skew divs with css

Tags: html, css, shapes

I have div and am wondering how I can angle/skew the bottom and right side slightly.

I can create triangles, and skew all sides, just not sure how to skew TWO sides.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: You need to show us some code you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to do it using `:before` and `:after` CSS selectors. I just whipped up a rough example.

<kbd>**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ubj4m/6/)**</kbd>

HTML:

```
<div class="slanted"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.slanted {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 380px;
    min-width: 380px;
    max-width: 380px;
    background: #000;
}

.slanted:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-right: 180px solid #000;
    border-top: 100px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 100px solid #fff; /* page background color */
}

.slanted:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-left: 200px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 200px solid #fff; /* page background color */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In newer browsers, you can use CSS transforms.

This code will skew a div:

```
-webkit-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0.6, 1, 250, 0);
-o-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0.6, 1, 250, 0);
transform: matrix(1, 0, 0.6, 1, 250, 0);
```

The result will look something like this:
[image]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/VvJ3L/)

The Mozilla Developer Network has [an article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) that tells more about the different transformations you can apply. It also has several examples and has [details about browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility).